# Replace class with new class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have an issue in replacing the class,i want to  replace the class using jquery or java script. i need to change the class which is inside the ul tag. how  i can  change it

```
 <ul  id="user-listview" class="userlist" data-bind="foreach:Items">
    <li>
   <span id="spname" data-bind="text:userName"  class="c-user"/><span>
   <div>
      <img id="imguser" data-bind="attr: { src:userImageUrl }" class="c-image" />
     </div>
   </li>
  </ul>

 // I am trying like below code but its doesn't work
  $(".userlist li #spname").removeClass('c-user').addClass('IPuser');
  $(".userlist li #imguser").removeClass('c-image').addClass('IPimage');
```

Comment: update your selector like '$(".userlist li#spname")'. Not include space in the same hierarchical element in selector

Answer (score 0):

```
window.document.getElementById("myId").classList.add("myNewClass");
```

And if you want to remove the previous class:

```
window.document.getElementById("myId").classList.remove("myOldClass");
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'classList' of null getting this error

Comment: @kittysarvaj That error is telling you that the element which you are trying to refer doesn't exist. Check if you wrote the id correctly, or if you are refering to a non-existent html element.

Comment: thanks for your time, i ll check